# How to fix python pyglet error for play and pause?

Tags: python, media-player, pyglet

i am trying to create an audio player using tkinter and a separate class for Player.
I have encountered an error. I can play the song when i call the Function "start_play_thread" , but afther i press/call the Function Pause and then i try to play again the song keeps looping same second from where i paused it.
Could someone help me, please?

```
import pyglet
import time
from threading import Thread

class Player():
    parent=None
    song_length=0
    current_song_time=0
    paused=False

    def play_media (self):
        try:
            self.myplayer = pyglet.media.Player()
            self.source = pyglet.media.load(self.parent.current_track)
            self.myplayer.queue(self.source)
            self.myplayer.play()

            pyglet.app.run()

        except:
            pass
    def start_play_thread(self):
        player_thread = Thread(target=self.play_media)
        player_thread.start()

        time.sleep(4)
        self.actual_song_time()

    def pause_song(self):
        try:
            self.myplayer.pause()
        except :
            pass

    def unpause_song(self):
        try:
            self.myplayer.play()
        except:
            pass

    def actual_song_lenght(self):
        try:
            self.song_lenght = self.source.duration
        except:
            self.song_lenght = 0
        return self.song_lenght

    def set_volume(self,value):
        try:
            self.myplayer.volume=value
        except:
            pass

    def actual_song_time(self):
        try:
            self.current_song_time = self.myplayer.time
        except:
            self.current_song_time = 0
        return  self.current_song_time
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('a pyglet player class implementation')
```

[First picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSnWx.jpg)

[Second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPIVQ.png)

Comment: Your indentation appeared pretty out of sync, so I *think* I corrected it correctly. If not, please feel free to post a code that works *(most of your functions had `self` as a parameter, but they were indented out side of the class, which made no sense)*

Comment: Regarding your issue, don't use threads while creating graphical applications unless you're absolutely sure on what you're doing. It's a slippery slope and can cause a lot of weird issues and crashes. Instead, use event handlers and events to trigger pause/play etc.

Comment: Update-i have posted my entire player code from my IDE Pycharm within 2 pictures.I have noticed that when i encounter that error if i remove/add something to usb port of my pc overpass the error and keeps playing normal.